# Join the result of two queries together

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I'm trying to join the results of two or more queries together. I have had a look at both `union` and `join` but can't seem to get the result i'm after. I want the result to be `id_competitor`, `total_products`, `discarted_products` (as columns). Any help on this is much appreciated

**EDIT:** Added pics of the query results as they stand.. I would like to join the tables together by `id_competitor. 
*The values should not be null*

Total prods: [total products query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8vc5T.png)
discarted:[discarted products query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MbVEg.png)

Query 1:

```
SELECT id_competitor, COUNT(competitor_product_variation.id_product) AS total_products 
        FROM competitor_product 
         JOIN competitor_product_variation USING(id_product) 
         WHERE is_related = 1 
         GROUP BY id_competitor
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT id_competitor, COUNT(competitor_product_variation.id_product) AS discarted_products 
    FROM competitor_product 
    JOIN competitor_product_variation USING(id_product) 
    WHERE is_related = 3 
    GROUP BY id_competitor
```

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 2):

Use conditional aggregation.

```
SELECT id_competitor
,sum(case when is_related = 1 then 1 else 0 end) AS total_products
,sum(case when is_related = 3 then 1 else 0 end) AS discarted_products 
FROM competitor_product 
JOIN competitor_product_variation USING(id_product) 
GROUP BY id_competitor
```

Edit: If all the `id_product` should be returned, use `left join` on `competitor_product` table. I assume all the products would be in this table.

```
SELECT cp.id_competitor
,sum(case when is_related = 1 then 1 else 0 end) AS total_products
,coalesce(sum(case when is_related = 3 then 1 else 0 end), 0) AS discarted_products 
FROM competitor_product cp
LEFT JOIN competitor_product_variation cpv on cp.id_product = cpv.id_product
GROUP BY cp.id_competitor
```

Comment: I would use `COUNT` with CASE and original `competitor_product_variation.id_product` we don't know for sure that it is nullable or not. Plus in MySQL you can skip case when `SUM(is_related = 1)` will work too.

Comment: @lad2025..i don't think the `competitor_product_variation.id_product` column would be `null`, as it is being used to `join` the tables. And `SUM(is_related = 1)` is more concise, i agree.

Comment: @vkp This works in the sense that the resulting query is constructed correctly but their values are incorrect

Comment: what makes you think so? it would help if you were to post some sample data and the expected result.

Comment: @vkp I did lol. I posted the data from my queries.. I want the results to join

Comment: based on *your* results, do you want all the `id_product` from `total products query?

Comment: @vkp I'm not sure I understand what you mean by all? I don't want to omit anything. Maybe it's the way I've phrased the question and even the way I'm expressing myself, so I am sorry. it was clealy posted wrong. But, Just the way I've displayed the total_products query.. the result should just be THAT with an extra column showing discarted products since they are practically the same code except for the where statement.

Comment: i get it..the discarded products query only returns 2 rows, which means that all the other id_competitors have no discarded products. So, i've modified the query to use a `left join`. Try the edited version.

Comment: @vkp The query just runs endlessly not displaying a result.. maybe its not optimized correctly?

Comment: could you set up a sql fiddle with some sample data?

Comment: @vkp Unfortunately, I think theres far too much data to try to set an example up on fiddle :/